# Issue with backbone.js and id with letters

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a problem with Backbone.js.
My system has inconsistency in the pattern of ID.

The fact is that the system has two types of ID:

1) id: 45 (integer, default and works properly)
2) id: app-45 (with problems)

The first problem is that the backbone "understands" this ID (id: app-45) as (id: app: 45)

The second problem is when I'll run an update, and the backbone sends the ID to 0.

Follows the details of the request:

**Headers:**
Request URL: localhost(...)
Request Method:PUT
Status Code:200 OK

**Request payload:**

{"id":"**app:120368",**"title":"Test"}

**Preview:**

reservation: {**id:app:0**, title:test }

**Response:**

{"reservation":{"id":"app:0","title":"test"

Answer (score 0):

You could always override the `.parse()` and `.toJSON()` methods of your model to transform `id` values, e.g.

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  parse: function(response){
    response.id = parseInt(response.id, 10); // or whatever function is appropriate
    return response;
  },
  toJSON: function(){
    var attrs = _.clone(this.attributes);
    attrs.id = "app-" + attrs.id; // or whatever reverses the transformation
    return attrs;
  }
})
```